# Removing a character, taking the number after that, removing the next and so on

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to do as follows in C#:
I have a string with the following data (this is an example with the longest string available, it is taken from a database, the database could return different numbers within the string depending on which ID i choose):
`|1|,|2|,|3|,|4|,|5|,|6|,|7|,|8|,|9|,|10|,|11|,|12|,|13|,|14|,|15|,|16|,|17|,|18|,|19|,|20|,|21|,|22|,|23|,|24|,|25|,|26|,|27|,|28|,|29|,|30|,|31|,|32|,|33|,|34|,|35|,|36|,|37|,|38|,|39|,|40|,|41|,|42|,|43|,|44|,|45|,|46|,|47|,|48|,|49|,|50|,|51|,|52|,|53|`

These are weeks of the year, I want to remove every "|" and "," and store each integer in one index in a list like so:

```
`
weekList[0] = 1
weekList[1] = 2
weekList[2] = 3
weekList[3] = 4
weekList[4] = 5
.
.
.
weekList[49] = 50
weekList[50] = 51
weekList[51] = 52
weekList[52] = 53
`
```

How can this be achieved ? I've read a lot about regex but couldn't find a way to do this at all...

Comment: `string.Split` with with multiple separators in a `char[]` should provide what you are looking for.

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing data that way in a DB.  Instead of one column with a list of values in a string format you should have a 1 to many relationship to a table that contains the individual values.

Comment: @juharr - I'm not the one storing them that way.. If it was me i would've only used integers and separated them with a comma. This is a DB that was made a while ago, and for me to edit every single row would be a big pain

Comment: @KZander Just to be clear the pipes are not the issue.  It's storing integer values as a comma separated string.  DBs are designed to represent a collection of data in a table.  Also if you do have the ability to fix the DB I'd highly suggest doing so.  You should be able to write code that will do the conversions for you.

Comment: Reading this a few years after... Damn i was a noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Split your string with a comma(`,`).

2) Trim each element in splitted string with character space() and pipe(`|`)

3) Parse each element to `int`

```
string str = "| 1 |,| 2 |,| 3 |,| 4 |,| 5 |,| 6 |,| 7 |,| 8 |,| 9 |,| 10 |,| 11 |,| 12 |,| 13 |,| 14 |,| 15 |,| 16 |,| 17 |,| 18 |,| 19 |,| 20 |,| 21 |,| 22 |,| 23 |,| 24 |,| 25 |,| 26 |,| 27 |,| 28 |,| 29 |,| 30 |,| 31 |,| 32 |,| 33 |,| 34 |,| 35 |,| 36 |,| 37 |,| 38 |,| 39 |,| 40 |,| 41 |,| 42 |,| 43 |,| 44 |,| 45 |,| 46 |,| 47 |,| 48 |,| 49 |,| 50 |,| 51 |,| 52 |,| 53 |";

int[] arr = str.Split(',')
               .Select(x => x.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '|' }))
               .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
               .ToArray();
```

Now here `arr`  is your integer array.

## Online Demo

**Alternative:**

1) Remove pipe(`|`) and whitespace().

2) Split with a comma(`,`).

3) Parse each splitted string to int.

```
int[] arr = str.Replace("|", "")
               .Replace(" ", "")
               .Split(',')
               .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
               .ToArray();
```

## Online Demo

Comment: The main thing I don't really understand is where is the part that it understands there are 2 integers after each other ? For ex. 21.. Is it at the Select(x => int.Parse(x)) ?

Comment: `Select(x => x.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '|' }))` <= this will gives you the list of strings instead of big integer as you think `123456789101112....`

Comment: and after above list we simply parse each item into integers, got it ?

Comment: see **Alternative** section in answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
        string str = "|1|,|2|,|3|,|4|,|5|,|6|,|7|,|8|,|9|,|10|,|11|,|12|,|13|,|14|,|15|,|16|,|17|,|18|,|19|,|20|,|21|,|22|,|23|,|24|,|25|,|26|,|27|,|28|,|29|,|30|,|31|,|32|,|33|,|34|,|35|,|36|,|37|,|38|,|39|,|40|,|41|,|42|,|43|,|44|,|45|,|46|,|47|,|48|,|49|,|50|,|51|,|52|,|53|";
        str = str.Replace("|", "");

        string[] subStrings = str.Split(',');
        int[] ints = new int[subStrings.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < subStrings.Length; i++)
        {
            ints[i] = Convert.ToInt32(subStrings[i]);
        }
```

Comment: glad i could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the regex approach that you asked for.
First you've to find all digits using Regex pattern **\d+**, this pattern matches one or more numbers. Use [Regexstorm tested](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test your regex. Loop through the matches and assign to your array.

Here is a sample which I came up with C# interactive:

```
string input = "| 1 |,| 2 |,| 3 |,| 4 |,| 5 |,| 6 |,| 7 |,| 8 |,| 9 |,| 10 |,| 11 |,| 12 |,| 13 |,| 14 |,| 15 |,| 16 |,| 17 |,| 18 |,| 19 |,| 20 |,| 21 |,| 22 |,| 23 |,| 24 |,| 25 |,| 26 |,| 27 |,| 28 |,| 29 |,| 30 |,| 31 |,| 32 |,| 33 |,| 34 |,| 35 |,| 36 |,| 37 |,| 38 |,| 39 |,| 40 |,| 41 |,| 42 |,| 43 |,| 44 |,| 45 |,| 46 |,| 47 |,| 48 |,| 49 |,| 50 |,| 51 |,| 52 |,| 53 |";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+");
int[] values = new int[matches.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    values[i] = Convert.ToInt32(matches[i].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(obj sender,EventArgs e)
{
String str = "|1|,|2|,|3|,|4|...";
char[] ch =str.ToArray(),weekList=new char[ch.Length];
Int index=1;
for (int i=1;i < ch.Length ;i++)
{
if(index < ch.length-1)
{
weekList[i] = ch[index];
Index += 4;
}
}
MessageBox.Show(weekList[0]);//1
MessageBox.Show(weekList[9]);//10
}
```